# How to subscribe to an operator in Rxjs6

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a function which uses the `zip` operator and I would like to return it as observable.

```
get(term) :Observable<any> {
   var word = this.searchWord(term); //Observable
   var suggestions = this.getSuggestions(term); //Observable
   return zip(word, suggestions)
}
```

I would like to subscribe to the `get()` method, but I'm getting an error saying:

> Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<{}, [{}, {}, any[]]>'.

On previous version I used to make this doing:

```
return Observable.zip(....
```

How can I do it now?

**EDIT**

It was my mistake, I was importing it from:

```
import { catchError, map, filter, zip } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

When I changed to:

```
import { Observable, throwError as observableThrowError, from, zip } from 'rxjs';
```

It worked.

Comment: Try this:  return zip(word, suggestions) as Observable

Comment: @siva636 `Type 'OperatorFunction<{}, [{}, {}, any[]]>' cannot be converted to type 'Observable<any>'.`

Comment: Are your imports correct? https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#import-paths

Comment: Here's a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-k3mif2?file=index.ts

Comment: @siva636 You are correct, I was importing from the wrong place. If you want to put a answer I will mark it as correct. I have edited the OP

Comment: I would like to comment that this answer, as explained, is slightly misleading. Particularly in light of the question you've written. The zip operator _does not_ return an `Observable`. Operators are intended to be used with the `.pipe` method on `Observable`s. By importing `zip` from `rxjs` you're importing a static method that behaves quite differently to the `zip` operator. Great that this answers your question though 